# Creacion de clase. ValueError: No engine for filetype: 'csv'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Aprendiendo a crear clases. Intento crear un clase que importe cotizaciones desde Yahoo y las exporte a ficheros .xlsx y .csv. El script desarrollado inicialmente como una función, opera correctamente, sin embargo, la versión que he desarrollado como clase, me devuelve un error que no entiendo. La clase es ésta:

```
class ImportadorExportadorYahoo (object):
    start = "2000-1-4"   
    end = date.today()

    def __init__(self, nombre, ticker, fichero_excel=None, fichero_csv=None): 
        #self.start = start
        #self.end = end
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.fichero_excel = fichero_excel
        self.fichero_csv = fichero_csv

    def actualizar(self):     
        df = pd_data.DataReader(ticker, "yahoo", self.start, self.end)
        print ("\nCotizaciones ", nombre," \n", df[:3])    
        df.to_excel (self.fichero_excel)   
        df.to_csv (self.fichero_csv)  

os.chdir("G:/Py_2019/Py_micartera_POO/Ficheros_Yahoo")

"""Nombres de columnas del fichero csv: "lista_nombres" y "lista_tickers" """
df = pd.read_csv("lista_valores.csv")
data = df[df["ID"] == "Y"]
for i in range(0,data.shape[0]):
    nombre = data["nombres"][i]
    ticker = data["tickers"][i]
    fichero_excel = data["ficheros_xlsx"][i] 
    fichero_csv = data["ficheros_csv"][i] 
    obj = ImportadorExportadorYahoo(nombre, ticker, fichero_excel, fichero_csv)
    obj.actualizar()
```

En este enlace
https://github.com/akitxu/Aprendiendo-GitHub

Se encuentra accesible el notebook "Clase_ImportarExportar_Yahoo.ipynb", y dentro de la carpeta "Ficheros" está el fichero "lista_valores.csv"

El error devuelto es:

```
ValueError: No engine for filetype: 'csv'
```

¿cual puede ser la causa?. Agradeceré vuestra ayuda.

Efectivamente, habia un error en el fichero "lista_valores.csv", pero solo afecta al nombre del fichero .csv que se va a crear en la exportación. La búsqueda en Yahoo la hace con los tickers del campo "tickers" del fichero lista_valores.csv". El ticker del "dow_jons" es "^GSPC". 
Compruebo que con este ticker no sale ningún error ejecutando.

```
start = "2000-1-4"   
end = date.today()
df = pd_data.DataReader("^GSPC", "yahoo", start, end)
df[:3]
```

Sin embargo, la clase me sigue dando el mismo error.

He probado el script en spyder y me devuleve el mismo error.

Comment: He cambiado las etiquetas para añadir `pandas` y quitar `anaconda`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el fichero `"lista_valores.csv"` hay un *gazapo*. Si te fijas, te sale bien los resultados hasta llegar a la línea de **Dow Jones**, que falla. Ahí aparece el fichero CSV `"dow_jones.csv"` que no existe, debería poner `"dow_jons.csv"`.

El motor (*engine*) de excel trata de leer el fichero. Como no lo encuentra, devuelve como referencia `None`, objeto que no tiene el atributo `csv`, que es lo que dice el primer error:

```
OptionError: "No such keys(s): 'io.excel.csv.writer'"
```

A su vez se produce otro error:

```
ValueError: No engine for filetype: 'csv'
```

Realmente, no parece que sean mensajes de mucha ayuda. Cambia de nombre el fichero o modifica el fichero `"lista_valores.csv"` para que no dé este error.

Comment: Efectivamente, ese era un error, pero solo afecta al nombre del fichero .csv que se va a crear. La búsqueda en Yahoo la hace con los tickers del campo "tickers" del fichero lista_valores.csv".

Comment: Gracias Chema, he corregido el error, aunque solamente afecta al nombre del fichero que se va a crear para la exportación.Me sigue dando el error.

Comment: OK. He probado el código y funciona sin errores. Comprueba la instalación de dependencias y prueba en otro entorno a ver si pasa lo mismo.  Sin poder reproducir el error, poco puedo ayudarte.

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia. ¿Qué es la instalación de dependencias?.

Comment: He probado en spyder y me devuelve el mismo error.

Comment: Ya he visto lo que se denomina dependencias. No pienso que sea ese el problema, ya que desarrollado el script como una función, opera sin problemas. Por otra parte, he creado alguna otra función que opera también correctamente.

Comment: He vuelto a crear un fichero"lista_valores.csv"  nuevo y ahora funciona correctamente. Luego es evidenter que el problema estaba en el fichero como tu deducías analizando el comportamiento del motor (engine)

Comment: Es frecuente que se cuele algún carácter de control que no le guste al sistema operativo como nombre de ficheros (eg: salto de líneas). Tal vez los mensajes de error deberían ajustarse más al problema que ha ocurrido.